# JBPM6 project connect to mysql failed

Tags: jboss, jbpm

i installed jbpm6 and mysql，i used PoolingDataSource to start BD，but always unable to find'squenses' tables，i kown it's hibernate'dialect problem，and i want to use persistence.xml to start .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <persistence
          version="2.0"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
          xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

      <persistence-unit name="com.test.test" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/jbpm-ds</jta-data-source>        

        <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>

        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>

        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>

        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationKeyInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationPropertyInfo</class>

        <!-- manager -->
        <class>org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.ContextMappingInfo</class>

        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.AttachmentImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ContentImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.BooleanExpressionImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.CommentImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DeadlineImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.CommentImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DeadlineImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DelegationImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EscalationImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.GroupImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.I18NTextImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.NotificationImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationHeaderImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.PeopleAssignmentsImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ReassignmentImpl</class>

        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskDataImpl</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.UserImpl</class>
        <!--BAM for task service -->
        <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.BAMTaskSummaryImpl</class>

        <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

          <!-- BZ 841786: AS7/EAP 6/Hib 4 uses new (sequence) generators which seem to cause problems -->      
          <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />            
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="jbpm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="jbpm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbpm"/>        
           <property name="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer" value="true"/>      
          <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>        
      </persistence-unit>    
    </persistence>
```

but the error is that:

```
​Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at test.test.createRuntimeManager(test.java:71)
at test.test.main(test.java:37)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/jbpm-ds]
at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
... 6 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: unable to find a bound object at name 'jdbc/jbpm-ds'
at bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixContext.lookup(BitronixContext.java:83)
at bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixContext.lookup(BitronixContext.java:67)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
... 19 more
```

i don't kown what i lose

Comment: can you share your standalone XML? Is there a JDBC data source configured with the name jdbc/jbpm-ds ?

Comment: datasouce is:<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS" pool-name="MariaDBDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbpm</connection-url>
                   <driver>mariadb</driver>
                  <security>
                   <user-name>jbpm</user-name>
                   <password>jbpm</password>
                    </security>
               </datasource>

Comment: So is jbpmDS the same as jbpm-ds?